# How to run PHP code using Sublime Text and direct output to the browser instead of the console

Tags: php, sublimetext2

I'm interested in switching to Sublime Text2 from Netbeans 8 for PHP development. (It's making mincemeat out of my 2008 MBP!) I've have figured out how to run PHP code using the Build System, which displays output in the ST2 console, from this [blog post](http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/06/sublime-text-2-advanced-techniques-part-2/). I'd like to display the output in my default browser instead of the console, just like the grownup IDE's do.

I plan to try XDEBUG next with this [blog post](http://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-xdebug-sublime-text-3/), but think getting this running first is a good place to start.

My code is

```
<?php
    phpInfo();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To make php work on the browser, you need to have a webserver running. Apache, nginx, IIS, etc. Look from LAMP server, or WAMP on windows.

Comment: why would you want your users to run PHP code? I'm curious, really.

Comment: I'm trying to make the switch from Netbeans and use Sublime Text as my IDE. I have a webserver (MAMP) no problem. What I want to know is how to get ST2 to run the code in my browser much as Netbeans would.

Comment: Have you tried [Xdebug](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Xdebug) plugin ? it doesn't output to browser, but you can set break points like you would do in an IDE.Edited: looks like it has something similar **Auto-launch web browser for session based debugging**

Comment: Unless you install a webserver as already suggested, you won't be able to. Netbeans is an IDE whereas ST is nothing but a glorified text editor. There are ST plugins that allow you refresh your browser and such, but that's it.

Comment: More info about ST plugins is what I'm looking for. Apache is my webserver, as indicated in my comment above (MAMP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the [Sublime Text plugin BrowserRefresh-Sublime](https://github.com/gcollazo/BrowserRefresh-Sublime). From the README:

> After installing this plugin you can hit <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> on Mac OS X or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> on Windows and Linux while using your favorite browser, the last active window will come to the foreground *(you can turn this off in Chrome, Canary, Safari, WebKit and Yandex on Mac)* and reload the active tab. If the current file is unsaved, it will be saved before the browser is activated and reloaded.